# Inconsistent colour for badge counts between top bar and flags history

Tags: bug, design, badges

The top part of the image are the badge counts as displayed in the top bar.
The bottom part are the badge counts as shown when looking at your flags history. `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/USERID`

You can see that the colour for showing the number of badges isn't the same. The difference is clearly visible for the gold and bronze badge counts, though not so much for the silver badge count.

[image]

Comment: None of the numbers are colored in the bottom example, not just gold.

Comment: @user289905 gray is close enough to silver so it looks almost the same..

Comment: It's also inconsistent with the author info box (the area that contains the author's name and profile picture at the bottom right of questions and answers).